# uninitialized constant Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed in elastic-search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm implementing elastic-search in rails  by following this tutorial

> https://iridakos.com/programming/2017/12/03/elasticsearch-and-rails-tutorial

And add these lines to my User.rb `include Elasticsearch::Model include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks`
& also installed these two gems `gem 'elasticsearch-model' gem 'elasticsearch-rails'` 
but when I try to execute this command `Post.import(force: true)` it gives me an error

> uninitialized constant Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed

Comment: You are missing the [Farraday](https://rubygems.org/gems/faraday/) gem.  Also, that tutorial is nearly 4 years out of date; you are likely to have all sorts of dependency issues.

Comment: oh sad , now my error is a little bit change, Faraday::ConnectionFailed (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (elasticsearch:9200))
integrate elastic-search is going to be a huge mountain for me :(

Comment: That just means you've not started started the elasticsearch service (on port 9200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes At the end I reached the solution in my case
As my project is a dockerized project & I was running elastic search locally that's why my app was not connected with elasticsearch.

When I Pull a docker image and run  elasticsearch from it after adding all credentials in my docker-compose.yml I successfully implement it.

Note: your kibana and elasticsearch version should be same.

My docker-compose.yml

```html
services: 

## My all services
elasticsearch:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.13
      environment:
        - cluster.name=docker-cluster
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
        - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
        - xpack.graph.enabled=false
        - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
        - discovery.type=single-node
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      networks:
        - eb-back_network
      volumes:
        - ./docker_data/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"

kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - eb-back_network
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```